# CLI output : killing the process in the middle but no required Output

Tags: go, curl, timeout, command-line-interface, irc

I am currently working on a project which requires me to send a curl request. The output of the request provides a link which expires in 10 seconds. The link starts a download. I am trying send the request and  downloading the file from the link in a go program. But the link providing output takes 10 seconds to complete and after that I cannot access the link. So I decided to kill the process prematurely using `timeout` command and I am able to download the needful. But when I try the same thing in Go, I am not able to get the output which would be displayed until it got killed.

I am only getting this output.

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 100  1320    0  1043  100   277     98     26  0:00:10  0:00:10 --:--:--    12
```

I use the following go script.

```
cmd := exec.Command("chmod", "744", "end.sh")
    out, err := cmd.Output()
    cmd1 := exec.Command("./end.sh")
    out, err = cmd1.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("cmd.Run(endpoint) failed with %s\n", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(out))
```

This code calls a shell script.

```
timeout 5 curl XXXXXXXXX
```

So what could I do to get the output, from shell script or go script modification?

Comment: Does it have to be curl? You can simply invoke the http request from go, and get the output you need without a need to exec curl.

Comment: Executing shell commands from Go is the wrong route to take 95% of the time. Generally you just want to recreate the behavior in native Go code.

Comment: That said your problem is most likely because `curl` issues different output when its stdout is connected to a tty versus when it is connected to another process.

Comment: It's "Go". Not "GO-Lang". And you shouldn't put tags in the title.